# How to remove Articles package from mean.io boilerplate

Tags: mean.io

Is there a way to remove the default Articles package without violating the rule of not modifying any of the default packages, specially for the sake of maintaining compatibility with any future updates to the framework?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the mean-CLI in command line. Just use the uninstall command:

```
mean uninstall articles
```